# Check if file exist or not?

Tags: iphone

i am new to iPhone programming.
What is the proper way to check that whether a file is exist or not?

Comment: What do you mean? Where is the file located? What type of file? Applications can *normally* only access local data from their own sandbox'd off section of the iPhone. Or are you talking about online files?

Answer (score 6):

```
BOOL isDirectory = NO;
if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
  fileExistsAtPath:path 
  isDirectory: &isDirectory ]) {
// file already exists

} else {
// file does not yet exist 

}
```

Comment: Can not be much more simple than this. This is a good showcase of my own rule of thumb: _"If I have written more then 10 lines of code, then I have probably missed a method already provided by Cocoa"_.

Answer (score 4):

To put it in more detail:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsDirectory]){

//Do something... 
}
```

You can append the actual file name to "documentsDirectory" like this: [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", spidermanpic]].

The isDirectory option in the answer above is used to check if the path is a directory or a file. Please keep in mind that it is a pointer. It wont work without the "&".